# How can i get the working directory inside a java package called from jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, package

sorry for the poor grammar.

How can I call getServletContext() inside a java program.

Basically i am using a java package inside a jsp application. I want to get the working directory somehow.

System.getProperty("user.dir") gives me the tomcat root dir which is not what i want.

Comment: working directory would be tomcat root only as it is running on tomcat, what did you expect ?

Comment: what do u actually want?

Comment: You're looking for the solution in the wrong direction. What's the functional requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call `getServletContext()`
>   inside a java program.

You can only if you define a `ServletContextListener`, something like this:

```
public class ServletContextHolder implements ServletContextListener{

    private static ServletContextHolder INSTANCE = null;

    public static ServletContextHolder getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public ServletContext getServletContext(){
        return servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent event){
        servletContext = null;
        INSTANCE=null;
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event){
        servletContext = event.getServletContext();
        INSTANCE=this;

    }
}
```

Define this as listener in your web.xml.

Now, from your running webapp, call it like this:

```
ServletContextHolder.getInstance().getServletContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton `ResourceLoader` and initialize it in a `ServletContextListener` by passing the `ServletContext` to it.
Then you can use this `ResourceLoader` to load any resource you need later, something like this:

```
public class ResourceLoader {

    private static ResourceLoader instance = new ResourceLoader();

    private ServletContext context;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private ResourceLoader(){
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static ResourceLoader getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param resourceName
     * @return
     */
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resourceName) {
        if(context == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("ResourceLoader is not initialized.");
        }
        return context.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public void setContext(ServletContext context){
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

you'll have to initialize it in the `ServletContextLister`'s `contextInitialized()` method as follows:

```
ResourceLoader.getInstance().setContext(servletContextEvenet.getServletContext());
```

and you can use anywhere else in your application:

```
ResourceLoader.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
```